# Android app where you can select a list of photos in full screen mode

Tags: android, photography, gallery

For quickly posting pics to Facebook, or uploading to cloud sync, I like a function to select a list of photos while viewing each photo on the full screen, and swiping through.

Ideally, I'd long-press the photo when I see it, and it places a tick mark which I can also unselect. That's opposed to doing the same in a tile view where I see square crops of multiple pictures.

I've tried (on my OnePlus Nord (Android)):

- My stock gallery
- Google Photos
- [Gallery - photo gallery, album from Photo Gallery Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gallery.photomanager.picturegalleryapp.imagegallery)

The requirement is that I need to be able to create a shareable list of photos while swiping through photos in full screen view.